# If $X^n$ is Lindelöf, then so is $\widetilde{X}^n$.

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group $T_2$, and $X$ a closed subspace of $G$. We suppose that, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $X^n$ is Lindelöf.

Consider $\widetilde{X}:=X\oplus\{e\}\oplus X^{-1}$ (we will assume that $x\neq e$ and $x\neq x^{-1}$ for each $x\in X$, thus these sets are disjoint).

In a book, the autor states (without a proof) that:

"For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\widetilde{X}^n$ is Lindelöf because $\widetilde{X}^n$ is a finite union of closed copies of the spaces $X^k$, with $k\le n$."

So, I don't understand two things:

1.- Why $\widetilde{X}^n$ is a finite union of closed copies of the spaces $X^k$, with $k\le n$?

2.- Why this implies that $\widetilde{X}^n$ is Lindelöf?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a space $Y$ and a positive integer $n$, let me write $nY$ for the discrete union of $n$ copies of $Y$. I’ll also write $\mathbf{1}$ for the one-point space.

First note that $X^{-1}$ is homeomorphic to $X$, so $\widetilde{X}$ is homeomorphic to $2X\oplus\mathbf{1}$. Let $Y=2X$. Then $\widetilde{X}^n$ is homeomorphic to $(Y\oplus\mathbf{1})^n$. If you write out the Cartesian product, you’ll find that

$$(Y\oplus\mathbf{1})^n=\bigoplus_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\left(Y^k\times\mathbf{1}^{n-k}\right)\;,$$

which is clearly homeomorphic to $$\bigoplus_{k=0}^n\binom{n}kY^k\;.$$ And

$$Y^k=(X\oplus X)^k=\bigoplus_{j=0}^k\binom{k}j\left(X^j\times X^{k-j}\right)=\bigoplus_{j=0}^k\binom{k}jX^k=2^kX^k\;,$$

so $\widetilde{X}^n$ is homeomorphic to $$\bigoplus_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k2^kX^k\;,\tag{1}$$

the discrete union of a finite number of copies of $X^k$ for $0\le k\le n$. (Note that $X^0$ is simply the space $\mathbf{1}$.)

By hypothesis each of the spaces $X^k$ with $k\le n$ is Lindelöf. Thus, if $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of the space $(1)$, then each of the subspaces $X^k$ can be covered by countably many members of $\mathscr{U}$. There are only finitely many of these subspaces, and the union of finitely many countable sets is still countable, so only countably many members of $\mathscr{U}$ are required to cover the space $(1)$. This space, and hence the homeomorphic space $\widetilde{X}^n$, is therefore Lindelöf.

We don’t actually need to know that the copies of $X^k$ are closed in $(1)$ (though of course they are both closed and open), and it would have been sufficient to know that there are countably many of them (rather than just finitely many): the argument that I just gave to show that the space $(1)$ is Lindelöf works whether or not the subspaces $X^k$ are closed, and it works even if there are countably infinitely many of them instead of finitely many.

Comment: Just wow. Your proof is amazing, and perfectly understandable. Thank you @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Surtan: You're very welcome.